# Error when trying to build Xamarin.Android after VS 2019 update

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I have a **Xamarin.Forms** App that used to work correctly, but after updating from **Visual Studio 2017** to **2019** I am getting an exception in Xamarin.Android when trying to build the solution. I have not changed anything in my code. The exception I get is:

```
   Error The "GenerateResourceDesigner" task failed unexpectedly.
   System.Xml.XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowInvalidChar(Char[] data, Int32 length, Int32 invCharPos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManagedResourceParser.Parse(String resourceDirectory, IEnumerable`1 additionalResourceDirectories, Boolean isApp, Dictionary`2 resourceMap)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateResourceDesigner.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() EventApp
```

I have tried every possible thing like uninstalling and reinstalling **Visual Studio 2019**. Clearing **bin** and **obj** folders but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know how can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem is resolved. it was some issue with Visual studio 2019. I clicked on Repair visual studio in VS installer , It took sometime and then my problem is solved. Anyway Thanks For help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated all NuGet packages? Checked all dependencies? Updated to VS 16.3.5? Although not getting the same error, I am having problems with the latest VS and XF coupled with Google Ads. Another suggestion that didn't help me, but has helped others, is to add

```
android:targetSdkVersion="28"
```

to the uses-permission tags. Is the Net Core version set properly?

Comment: Yes All Nugest packages are updated. Dependencies are resolved. VS is updated to 16.3.5. target SdkVersion is "28". 
everything is fine and working in other PC's but not mine. @Stephen Link

Comment: How about the Net Core version - 2.0? 2.1? Is there a NULL value in your code somewhere? See Jan 4 comment - https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2335

Comment: Replace Properties.xml with a clean copy.